# .htaccess mod_rewrite not working in localhost

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have Enabled mod_rewrite but still .htaccess is not working . It is not effecting but if i write something wrong in .htaccess file then it does show server error. In my htdocs i have folder called myfile .

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^myfile/PHP/project/$ /myfile/PHP/project/about.php
```

Comment: Where is this .htaccess located?  Verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting same garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not?

Comment: @ anubhava .htaccess is located in project folder and .htaccess is enabled

Comment: @Mark my goal is when we go to project folder in localhost, instead of listing out all the directories and files, it should open about.php file.

Comment: to avoid listsing use `Options -Indexes` in .htaccess file, and you can also redirect using PHP: add redirection header in index.php file.
edit: above code is working on my localhost.

Comment: @NikhilSupekar I do not recommend using PHP for redirects. The web server should handle that it does it more effectively. It's also done before any php is executed.

Comment: hmm.. you are right. @ChimedPalden if the .htaccess file is placed in root public directory the code should work.

Comment: @ChimedPalden: Is .htaccess placed in `/myfile/PHP/project/`? Also what is your `DocumentRoot` path?

Comment: @anubhava  DocumentRoot is C:/xampp/htdocs is yes .htaccess is palced in /myfile/PHP/project/

Comment: This is strange. So `myfile`  directory is not even under `C:/xampp/htdocs`?

Comment: yup, do you have any suggestion to fix it.

Comment: Well it cannot work. You cannot access any file/folder outside `DocumentRoot`. Your `/myfile/PHP/project/` should be moved below `DocumentRoot` to become: `C:/xampp/htdocs/myfile/PHP/project/` to start with.

Answer (score 0):

If you are placing .htaccess file in project directory then use following code,

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^\.*$ /myfile/PHP/project/about.php
```

The code in your question only work if the .htaccess file is placed public root directory.

Also, to disable directory listing add following code (case-sensitive) in .htaccess file.

```
Options -Indexes
```

Comment: yes, just edited my answer again, I was facing browser cache problem.

Comment: I don't now why but it is not effecting at all.

Comment: what error do you get? and is it the same code as in this ans.?

Comment: Access forbidden!  Error 403

Comment: so the problem seems to be with server configuration. Check this ans. [mod_rewrite not working](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17869097/4381432)

Answer (score 0):

You have to turn your "AllowOverride" to "all" and add this "Options FollowSymLinks" in your virtualhost or httpd.conf

Comment: i forgot "Options FollowSymLinks" , i update my answer

Comment: dont forgot to restart apache

Comment: Should i add "Options FollowSymLinks" at the top of httpd.conf