# apache mod_rewrite module not installing

Tags: macos, apache, mod-rewrite, apache2, httpd.conf

In my attempt to get my Drupal alias links to work I have narrowed it down to the fact that the mod_rewrite module is not installed. I uncommented the LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/apache2/mod_rewrite.so as well as LoadModule php5_module        libexec/apache2/libphp5.so. I have also changed AllowOverride None to AllowOverride All in every instance it appears in the httpd.conf file. I then restarted apache and I still cannot run this command: sudo a2enmod rewrite. Everytime I run it I get command not found error. What am I doing wrong, my username.conf also has the code listed below.

```
<Directory "/Users/username/Sites/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Any help would very appreciated.

Tyler

Comment: I think I found the answer that you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/869092/how-to-enable-mod-rewrite-for-apache-2-2 if that does not work try this http://serverfault.com/a/455892/305162

Comment: @Alex I took a look at that and it didn't seem to help, I'm wondering if there is a bigger problem, because I can't run any apache commands, I tried reinstalling apache and I couldn't even run this command sudo serveradmin stop web. Am I possibly running two instances of apache that I don't know about?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the terminal and type `sudo apachectl stop` and then `sudo apachectl start` and see what happens.

Comment: I ran sudo apachectl -k restart and sudo apachectl restart and everything worked fine. I ran phpinfo() and it said mod_rewrite is loaded. It doesn't seem write that php says its loaded but I still can't call the command to install it.

Comment: Go to this answer and see if it works http://stackoverflow.com/a/17869097/4700944