# .htaccess not redirecting to .php files

Tags: php, .htaccess

I need to redirect the following pages to their .php versions.

```
http://www.kgolf360.com/about
http://www.kgolf360.com/news
http://www.kgolf360.com/junior-performance-programs
http://www.kgolf360.com/before-after
http://www.kgolf360.com/book-lesson
http://www.kgolf360.com/family-performance-programs
http://www.kgolf360.com/technology
http://www.kgolf360.com/adult-performance-programs
```

For example, I need to redirect

```
http://www.kgolf360.com/about
```

to

```
http://www.kgolf360.com/about.php
```

etc.

What I did is modified my .htaccess file by adding the following:

```
Redirect 301 /about http://www.kgolf360.com/about.php
```

but it gives me a 404 error. You can see it if you go to http://www.kgolf360.com/about

Is it possible that I need to configure something else to make it work? If so, what exactly do I need to do to redirect the URLs properly?

Here's the content of my .htaccess file:

```
rewriteengine on
rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.kgolf360.com$ [OR]
rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^kgolf360.com$
rewriterule ^about$ "http\:\/\/kgolf360\.com\/about\.php" [R=301,L] #5682a68c22ecf
rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^kgolf360.com$
rewriterule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.kgolf360\.com\/$1" [R=301,L] #567eeb84dcae2


# The following will allow you to use URLs such as the following:
#
#   example.com/anything
#   example.com/anything/
#
# Which will actually serve files such as the following:
#
#   example.com/anything.html
#   example.com/anything.php
#
# But *only if they exist*, otherwise it will report the usual 404 error.
Options +FollowSymLinks
# Redirect to HTML if it exists.
# e.g. example.com/foo will display the contents of example.com/foo.html
# Redirect to PHP if it exists.
# e.g. example.com/foo will display the contents of example.com/foo.php
rewritecond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
rewritecond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
rewritecond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
rewriterule ^(.+)$ $1.html [L,QSA]
rewritecond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
rewritecond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
rewritecond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
rewriterule ^(.+)$ $1.php [L,QSA]

#Redirect all non-php URLs to their php versions

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Do you guys see any issues with the content I have in the fle now?

Comment: Do you have Apache's mod_alias enabled?  If it isn't, `Redirect` directives will be ignored and /about will return a 404.

Comment: also check if mod_rewrite is enabled and your server is configured to use it.. It sounds silly but thats the root of problem in many times.

Comment: This might be helpful, too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17868819/apache-mod-rewrite-not-working-with-htaccess-file

Comment: Yes, mod_alias is enabled on my Linux server (I'm with GoDaddy).

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using Godaddy, you need to use `Options +MultiViews`. So try this code:

```
Options +MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: I've added the chunk of code you recommended, but it did not do the trick. Please take a look at my updated question. I added my .htaccess file's content to it. Perhaps there's some sort of conflict in the file?

Comment: Looks ok, but how about describing it ? :) upvoted though

Comment: Well, it's my customer's .htacccess file (done by his web developer). I'm just an SEO guy who tried to figure out why I can't redirect the standard way :) Is there still hope for me? :)

Comment: Should have told me before, that you are using GoDaddy. Please try the updated solution. And for more information visit: http://alexcican.com/post/how-to-remove-php-html-htm-extensions-with-htaccess/